Async/Await exception handling confusion
I'm trying to understand async/await in .net8, especially exception handling and I'm running into some confusion, especially regarding the documentation as while it specifies some of the approach it doesn't give enough examples for me to understand what's happening.
I'm using the following trivial code just to watch something work:
private static async Task Main(string[] args) {
 var sleeps = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 0 };
 var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
 foreach (var t in sleeps)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Submitting task: {0}", t);
     tasks.Add(sleep(t));
 }
 Console.WriteLine("All tasks submitted, waiting for all to complete");
 try
 {
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
 } catch (DivideByZeroException e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks failed: {0}", e);
 }
 Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed, collecting results");
 foreach (var t in tasks)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Task returned: {0}", t.Result);
 }
}

 private static async Task<int> sleep(int s)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for: [ {0} ]", s);
     if (s == 0)
     {
         // this is just to throw something to be caught
         throw new DivideByZeroException("0 can't be delayed");
     }
     await Task.Delay(s * 1000);
     Console.WriteLine("\tSlept for: [ {0} ]", s);
     return s;
 }

I'm following documentation from here:

​Asynchronous programming with async and await - Asynchronous exceptions

and here:

Create and throw exceptions - Exceptions in task-returning methods.

According the docs I should try to throw exceptions in my async functions BEFORE entering the async portion of the code. Which you can see in my example I am, I am throwing a ZeroDivision exception before awaiting the Task.Delay.
When I run this code in visual studio, I would expect to hit my DivideByZeroException catch block, but instead I get a SystemAggregateException, which I understand is how .net collects all of the async exceptions, however the documentation explicitly states: When code awaits a faulted task, the first exception in the AggregateException.InnerExceptions collection is rethrown. However, I am not getting the DivideByZero exception thrown at all, instead I am getting 2 SystemAggregate exceptions throw sequentially each with their first innerException being the DivideByZero exception.
What is going on here.
I have also coded the breakfast example here: Asynchronous programming with async and await and added the toaster on fire there is even more confusing, in that I DO NOT get an exception throw anywhere when I explicitly throw one. I must inspect the Task.Exception to see if it was thrown.
So can anyone explain what is happening here?
What is the approach I would use if I wanted to submit 5 async tasks, wait for all of them to complete and then iterate over them to inspect either their Result or Exception properties? I am not understanding when to try/catch, when to inspect Task.Exception and why I'm getting SystemAggregate exceptions in my example code.

Before Task.WaitAll() you missed the await keyword.

If you should look into task.Result or task.Exception can be checked via task.State.

Never use Task.WaitAll() or any other blocking method, but Task.WhenAll() instead.

@Oliver Task.WaitAll() - Cannot await void.

@Peregrine - Never like, MS should have never published this method or your opinion is I shouldn't? What if I want to block until they are all done?

@user22335954 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1325809/task-whenall-task-waitall

@user22335954 https://medium.com/@rahman3593/a-deep-dive-into-task-waitall-and-task-whenall-in-c-1a8cc145067b

@user22335954 Task.WaitAll() will block the main thread until all tasks have completed - quite the opposite of what you actually want to do.

@Peregrine: In fact, there is no good or bad, it mainly depends on your usage scenario. Thanks for the low-effort comments!

@user22335954 as you highlighted, the first inner exception from AggregateException is rethrown when task is awaited. Synchronous versions like Task.WaitAll, throw AggregateException, they do not await operations in a non-blocking awaiting, they do it via  blocking behavior  and throws just AggregateException. As it was designed in tasks before introducing async/await keywords.

Moreover, apart from simple workhorse tasks that complete or fails with single exception, there are kinda compound tasks, that represent tree-like structure, or collection structure, where many exceptions might be, and these cases require special treating (eg AggregateException.Flatten method).

Also don't forget to checkout behavior TaskCancelledException and its base OperationCancelledException. Async/await actually doesn't work with TaskCancelledException (TCE for short, not in all cases at least). So TCE is part of not-reliable api here.

@Ryan, so awaitable Tasks will throw the first inner exception (when only 1 exception exists), but sync functions (Task.WaitAll) do the aggregate. I guess I just have to know that about WhenAll vs WaitAll. I'm still not following how to differentiate tasks that have failed. I see no examples anywhere in the docs of anyone inspecting the task.Status. What is the point of having to both catch a raised async exception AND also determine which task raised it by inspecting each of the completed tasks?


What is the point  - that's by design, i am not sure what principles lead to this, but having only one exception is enough to treat compound task (Task.WhenAll) being faulted, that's pretty reasonable. And yes, you have to enumerate those tasks and find faulted one by checking Task.Exception property. As answer below mentioned, the specific exception being thrown is changed (earlier it was first task in the collection passed to Task.WhenAll, now it is last, i have not checked it though). And we are not touching tree-like tasks yet...)


@Ryan you may want to take a look at the Comments page in the help center, to be informed about the intended usage of the comments in StackOverflow. They are mainly intended for improving the question, either by asking the OP for clarifications or by suggesting improvements.


I should try to throw exceptions in my async functions BEFORE entering the async portion of the code

You can split your implementation between an async function and a non-async function. Here I've done that by writing a local function for the async implementation;
private static Task<int> sleep(int s)
 {
     if (s == 0)
         throw new DivideByZeroException("0 can't be delayed");
     return sleepasync(s);

     async Task<int> sleepasync(int s){
         Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for: [ {0} ]", s);
         await Task.Delay(s * 1000);
         Console.WriteLine("\tSlept for: [ {0} ]", s);
         return s;
     }
 }

Otherwise the caller would need to await the returned task before the exception would be thrown. Not to say that your function is wrong, just that these functions have different semantics.
There's a subtle difference between failing to start a Task and returning a Task which has already failed. But in most cases this difference doesn't really matter.

You haven't actually answered any of my questions. You've just offered an alternative implementation without any explanation.

The other answer covers Task.WaitAll and the AggregateException, because any number of tasks could have thrown. My method is not that same as yours, because it may throw when sleep is called, not when the returned task is awaited. In the same way as the documentation you linked to.

The AggregateException is not thrown by your asynchronous sleep method. It is thrown by the synchronous Task.WaitAll method:

Exceptions
AggregateException
At least one of the Task instances was canceled. If a task was canceled, the AggregateException contains an OperationCanceledException in its InnerExceptions collection.
-or-
An exception was thrown during the execution of at least one of the Task instances.

The best solution to your problem is most likely to replace the Task.WaitAll with the asynchronous Task.WhenAll:
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (DivideByZeroException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks failed: {0}", e);
}

This will also eliminate a warning that you are probably seeing regarding the async Task Main method not containing any await.
In case you want to wait synchronously the tasks, and you like the behavior of await of propagating just one exception, you can use the .GetAwaiter().GetResult() like this:
try
{
   Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (DivideByZeroException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks failed: {0}", e);
}

This will block the current thread until all tasks complete, and will propagate the exception of one of the failed tasks, the first or last either positionally or chronologically, depending on the .NET runtime version. You can look at this GitHub issue for details about which task's exception is propagated.

The WhenAll vs WaitAll makes a bit more sense, one is the Aggregate and the other one is unwinding the innerException. I still don't understand or have seen any example of how to determine which tasks failed. Suppose I am waiting on 100 tasks to complete with Task.WhenAll. Even if I get 99 exceptions, I still don't know which tasks those were raised from. Do I just iterated over all of the tasks at completion time and inspect Task.Status to see if I can get a legitimate result of display the raised Task.Exception?

@user22335954 yes, you have the enumerate the tasks and see which one IsFaulted. The Task.WhenAll/Task.WaitAll APIs don't propagate all the state of the waited tasks. If you are dealing with advanced scenarios like the one in your question, you have to keep around your original tasks so that you can inspect them one by one after all have completed.
